# Modern web-applications architecture

Tags: web-applications, architecture, application-design, web-architecture

Good day, Stackoverflow community.

I've been little bit out of touch with current best practices for scalable web-application design/development. This is more of an ask for help to point in right direction.

I am planning an application with React.js on the front-end. There are still lots of shady/gray areas on how to structure the rest of the application. For example after some research I found that there were some suggestions to do the following:

- React (or Angular) front-end runs on Node/Express server
- The same server manages User authentication with ACL
- User data is stored in MongoDB (or any other light weight) with direct access from front-end server
- API is run separately on any other framework (Java, Go, Python, etc) but on the same domain (for example api.something.com)
- API/application data is stored in separate database (Mongo, Postgress, MySQL, Oracle, etc)
- All 3rd party API services are managed though API

What else should I consider and is there a resource that would guide me through best full stack architecture patterns? I know there are lots of resources, but it is mid 2018 and lots of patterns evolved drastically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use functional programming and separate code into sections to be uploaded to npm modules and pulled in. This way can facilitate pulling in only what is needed and reduces bloat. Disadvantage is that you need to know or check what is available. Advantage is can make available to only certain groups.

Comment: Question is very vague. Like how do I do good software development. It depends on the project eg. real-time, data driven, backend vs ui focused, etc etc